# How do I pass scroll events from my View to CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, view, android-coordinatorlayout

`Material Design` has this fancy pattern of scrolling/hiding/pinning parts of the `ToolBar/ActionBar` when some View below gets scrolled. I have my own, very specialized view, that isn't a descendant of `RecyclerView` (that probably handles this by default), so it doesn't work with scroll behaviors. I suspect I need to pass some scroll information up to Coordinator-layout to handle hide on scroll. But how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to look at a support class called `NestedScrollingChildHelper` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChildHelper.html)).

You can easily graft this helper class onto your scrolling view.  Have your class implement `NestedScrollingChild`, instantiate a delegate instance, then delegate all the interface methods to that instance.

Finally, whenever you are processing a scroll or a fling, you call these methods to see if the `CoordinatorLayout` will consume the motion events before you scroll your view.

Here's a piece of code from `NestedScrollingChild.onTouchEvent()` to show you nested scrolling in action:

```
            final int y = (int) MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, activePointerIndex);
            int deltaY = mLastMotionY - y;
            if (dispatchNestedPreScroll(0, deltaY, mScrollConsumed, mScrollOffset)) {
                deltaY -= mScrollConsumed[1];
                vtev.offsetLocation(0, mScrollOffset[1]);
                mNestedYOffset += mScrollOffset[1];
            }
```

See line 766 of this file: [NestedScrollView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.java).  BTW, this class uses the `NestedScrollingChildHelper` delegate, so you can see exactly how it all works.

Don't forget to use `ViewCompat` instead of `View`, `ViewGroupCompat` instead of `ViewGroup`, etc.